# Sitecore - Prevent access to a page, but still show it in the navigation

Tags: authentication, sitecore

In Sitecore I have denied access to a particular page for the anonymous user.

This works correctly, but it also means that the page does not appear in the navigation menus and sitemap (both XSLT).

What I would like is for the user to be able to see the link, but be redirected to a Register/Login page when they click on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to allow anonymous users to view the page for it to be visible in the menu and sitemap.

What you could do though is override the **Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestProcessor** to check if the page requires a login (by adding a RequiresLogin True/False to the template for example), then check if the user is logged in if not redirect to your login page.

Theres an example of overriding the HttpRequestProcessor [here](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/sitecore-displaying-pages-without-a-language-version/)

Comment: This worked great, and provides a simpler method of restricting access to pages for users who might find the User Manager a bit intimidating.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the rendering logic in the menus in a SecurityDisabler, so it would render all item links, even if the user "cant see" them.

```csharp
using (SecurityDisabler disabler = new SecurityDisabler())
{
  foreach (Item item in Sitecore.Context.Item.Children)
  {
    ... render the link ...
  }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as the code provided is for an ascx not a xslt. You could however use the <sc:disableSecurity> tag